# analysis of a binary file, homework problem

Tags: binary

I have been given the task of finding a password token as part of a course i am doing. However, it isn't making much sense to me. Would someone possibly be able to help me? The task is as follow:

"Analyse the binary to get the password token.
In this task, you will be analysing the binary called ‘level1’ that is located in the /home/linux folder of the virtual machine. Use popular binary analysis tools to complete this task."

I don't really understand what they mean by popular binary analysis tools. I used the cat command to see what is in the level 1 file and it comes up with a bunch of random characters (which I am assuming is machine code). How would i go about doing this?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: try `hexdump -C` ; it'd be the first tool I'd use.  (`man hexdump` for info)

Comment: it worked!! thank you so much <3 @guiverc

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it works :-)

Answer (score 3):

Try

`hexdump -C filename`

It would be the first tool I'd use  (*filename* should be replaced by your actual filename).

If you need details for the command, use `man hexdump` which will show you the reference manual page for the command hexdump.

Comment: A good alternative would be `strings` :) I'm lazy... :)